# Accessing implicit setter/getter

Tags: coldfusion, getter-setter, cfc, railo

I have a component with a couple property definitions and an init() method. I am able to access getUuid() but not getSandwich().

```
component output="false" accessors="true" {
  property
    name="uuid"
    type="string"
    default=""
    hint="The sandwich ID";
  property
    name="sandwich"
    type="string"
    default=""
    hint="The fucking sandwich";

  public any function init() {
    this.setUuid(CreateUUID());
    this.setSandwich = "Peanut Butter and Banana";
    return this;
  }

}
```

The Uuid property and corresponding getSandwich() method are available in the instance as expected where in the case of sandwich, the property is not set even though the value is applied to the setSandwich() method.

[image: sandwich machine]

Comment: *Re: this.setSandwich = "Peanut Butter and Banana";* Is that a typo or bug? Did you mean `this.setSandwich("Peanut Butter and Banana")`?

Comment: O my, that's a goofy bug that I just couldn't see. It's been a weird day for me. Thank you for your eyes. I'd check this as the answer if it were presented as one. For now, plus one for you.

Comment: I hear ya'. Logic bugs are easy for tired eyes to miss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From the comments)

> `this.setSandwich = "Peanut Butter and Banana";`

Is that a typo or bug (ie that overwrites the `setSandwich()` method with a simple string)? Did you mean:

```
this.setSandwich( "Peanut Butter and Banana" );
```

?